# React style property is not updating more than once after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inline-styles

I have a piece of React code that looks like this:

```
<li style={selected
       ? null
       : globals.unselectedLiStyle} key={"selectable_" + headsign}>
```

`selected` is a boolean that determines how the particular `<li>` should look. The default state is unselected so initially the `globals.unselectedLiStyle` style is applied. This works fine. When the state gets toggled the first time, the `globals.unselectedLiStyle` is removed from the `<li>` and the page renders correctly. Now the issue is when the state gets toggled once more. I have confirmed that after a second toggle `selected == false`, however the `globals.unselectedLiStyle` is not reapplied.

I thought this might have something to do with the `<li>` not being fully rerendered but it looks like that is not the case. Forcing the `<li>` to rerender did no good. Otherwise I am at a total loss. Any help or direction is appreciated. Is this simply not allowed in React?

Comment: You might need to add more code to trace the `selected` variable.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo Can you be more specific? I have confirmed it is the right value at the right times. Is there something else?

Comment: Just post the rest of the code.

Comment: is not updating, same issue